# How do I indicate collate order in Roxygen2?

Tags: r, documentation-generation, roxygen2

Using roxygen2 documentation with devtools `document` function automatically generates a `Collate:` field in the package DESCRIPTION, regardless of whether or not it is necessary to load the package library files in a particular order.

I'm working on a package with a bunch of S4 methods and want to be sure the class definitions are loaded before any methods or other classes using them, which I understand I can do with the `Collate` list, but I'm not sure how to indicate this in the roxygen2 documentation format.

The [roxygen2 manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/roxygen2.pdf) makes some reference to an `@include` tag but that looks like it might actually just include code in the documentation, for instance, for adding external examples through an `@examples` flag.  Can this be used for specifying collate order for methods?

Comment: If the collate field is already in the DESCRIPTION roxygen2 doesn't generate it.  So I'd say you have to make the order you want and it should be respected.  (I think; hence the comment vs an answer).

Comment: it would be nice to know if my @import interpretation is correct.  It also certainly would be nice to have a function figure out the collate order from a list of file dependencies rather than having to work it out manually.

Comment: import is used to import a package.  This is similar to listing a package in the Depends section except that it is much cleaner because it doesn't pollute the user's namespace.

Comment: And let me save you future heart ache by saying `@importfrom` is even better because it avoids naming conflicts.

Comment: whoops, I meant to say `@include` is the tage I don't understand, sorry for the typo.  Text changed above.  What's up with the `@include` tag and how does it relate to `Collate` ordering?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The include tag is used to state that one file needs another to work. (The name include might not have been the best choice, but such is life). If you want to make sure that file B is loaded before file A, then make sure to `@include B` in A. Roxygen will take care of ordering the collate field to satisfy your restrictions.

Comment: brilliant, so include does just what I need!

Answer (score 5):

I just figured out that if you add the @include statement at the top of your R file, it will interfere with the next roxygen2 documentation block unless you follow it with a NULL eg

```
#' @include something.R
NULL

#' Documenting a function
#'
#" It does something...
#'
#' @param ...
#'
```

Comment: I find it useful to include `#' @include file-with-class-definitions.R` at the head of any roxygen block defining a method for an S4 class that is in a different file from the class definition. That way you are certain to have the class defined before the method is defined, even if the file containing the class definition is alphabetically prior to the filename defining the method. Better safe than sorry!