# In R, how can I subclass an object from an imported class in my package?

Tags: r, oop, devtools, roxygen2

I'm working on an R package and import a certain library.  I am making a class that inherits a class from the imported library.

In my DESCRIPTIONS file I have:

```
...
Imports:
    importedPackage
```

Then I have a class declaration:

```
setClass("mySampleClass",
     slots = list(
       numUp = "numeric",
       numDown = "numeric"
     ),

     contains = "classToExtend"
)
```

If I am importing importedPackage, I know I need to reference the functions from that package as `importedPackage::someFunction()`.  I can't do that though here with the `contains =` part in my class declaration.  Right now, it tells me at build time:

```
Error in reconcilePropertiesAndPrototype(name, slots, prototype, superClasses,  : 
   no definition was found for superclass “importedPackage::classToExtend” in the specification of class “mySampleClass”
```

I've tried a few different ways of fixing this.  It seems like the sort of issue that someone must have faced before, but I'm unable to find how to do this properly by google so far.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: So I don't do much with S4, so this is a guess, but have you tried what the first answer on this QA says? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897002/include-an-s4-object-from-an-existing-package-as-a-slot-in-a-new-s4-class. It seems like maybe that would take care of your issue too?

Comment: Interestingly that question is about the exact same package I'm trying to import.  I have tried that and several variations of it.  It seems to document and then build okay, but right after the build it does `library(MyLib)` and looks fine, but then the next time I click anywhere it crashes with fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. If you have S4 classes with inheritance relationships and the classes are in different .R files, then the file containing the superclass (classToExtend) has to be loaded before the subclass (mySampleClass).

This can be done using roxygen2 package where you document in mySampleClass file,

```
#' @include <file name containing classToExtend definition>
```

This basically means apply to that file rather than the immediate code line followed below.

So this basically creates a collate field in the DESCRIPTION file and dependencies are listed first.

Then finally, in order for the roxygen to perform the collate operation, you may need to manually run it.

```
roxygen2::update_collate(<package name>)
```

If you want to fully generate documentation, include any NAMESPACE changes then use

```
devtools::document(<package name>)
```

Here is a question, that talks about including collate order: [How do I indicate collate order in Roxygen2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544006/how-do-i-indicate-collate-order-in-roxygen2)

Here is roxygen2 documentation: http://roxygen.org/roxygen2-manual.pdf

Comment: Hi Abhiskehk, please format the code portion of your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I appreciate the provided link for formatting. Learning how to use stack overflow :)